# Eclipse not giving warning when running java code which has compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, spring-tool-suite, sts

When running a Java/Spring code, If the application has compilation errors we get a popup warning as " Code contains compilation error..Continue running ". There is a checkbox there as " Do not ask next time" I ticked that and allowed, Now Even if my large Java/spring applications contains compilation error it still runs and I am not able to find if my code contains errors. Can anyone help me to revert to that old setting of popup warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert this Eclipse setting in the **preferences *Run/Debug > Launching*** by setting ***Continue launch if project contains errors*** to ***Prompt***:

[image: Eclipse Setting]